# How do you determine VMCG, if its yawing moment by the inoperative engine is only be corrected by the rudder?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance, engine-failure, rudder, v-speeds

The requirement of VMCG is:
VMCG, the minimum control speed on the ground, is the calibrated airspeed during the takeoff run at which, when the critical engine is suddenly made inoperative, it is possible to maintain control of the airplane using the rudder control alone (without the use of nosewheel steering), and the lateral control to the extent of keeping the wings level. In the determination of VMCG, assuming that the path of the airplane accelerating with all engines operating is along the centerline of the runway, its path from the point at which the critical engine is made inoperative to the point at which recovery to a direction parallel to the centerline is completed may not deviate more than 30 feet laterally from the centerline at any point.

How do you determine, this speed by preliminary design? Can it be said, that the centrifugal force is the same as the delta of the engines inoperative? So the Centripetal force is by the rudder if we neglect the tire forces?

Comment: In preliminary design it should be the other way around: you have the value of vmcg as requested for example by some regulations and you design the rudder accordingly.

Comment: Not sure that centrifugal & centripetal forces are really what's at work... you have a force on a moment arm from the running asymetric engine (no longer balanced by the now-dead engine), and you have a force & moment arm from the rudder, and you want those to be at least in balance (or slightly more provers yaw available from the rudder to return to a straight-ahead track).